# Laravel: Change app url in routes called inside queued notifications

Tags: laravel

I'm developing a tenant-based application and want to customized notifications for each tenant. My problem is that once Laravel queue starts running, it reads `APP_URL=olddomain.com` environment variable and use it for each route generated inside notifications. Even if I try to change the config using `config(['app.url' => 'newdomain.com'])`, it will still output any route with `olddomain.com` prefix. I can pass `newdomain.com` as a parameter to the notification and do something like this:

```
$domain = "newdomain.com"; 
$route = route('named-route', [{parameters}], false);
$finalRoute = $domain . '/' . $route; (Output: newdomain.com/named-route)
```

But this seems too "hacky". Is it possible to change `app.url` for each individual notification in queue?

Comment: I think that has no way to generate a customized url, because the reason of the URL generator is get the current URL and generate a full url of it, imagine that to generate a custom url you have to give the domain and the params, to you basically give the all new url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this, put this in your *'app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php'* inside of your *boot* method put this:

```
app()->singleton('new-domain', 'https://newdomain.com');
```

then, execute `php artisan config:cache` in your terminal (in your project folder) and then call it wherever you want with this:

```
$myCustomizedDomain = app('new-domain');
$myCustomizedUrl = $myCustomizedDomain . "/my-prefix";
```

Because there is no way to do what you are looking for, sorry.

**EDIT:**

I found this in the laravel documentation version-6x:

> - **Redirecting To External Domains**
>
> Sometimes you may need to redirect to a domain outside of your
>   application. You may do so by calling the away method, which creates a
>   RedirectResponse without any additional URL encoding, validation, or
>   verification:
>
> `return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com');`

this allows you to redirect to some page outside of your application from the sever-side.

Answer (score 0):

If you change a variable inside the .env file make sure to run `php artisan config:cache` or `php artisan cache:clear` so it reads if variables has changed

Comment: Cannot use just one setting in config or .env, notifications are sent from tenants interchangeably, any change in route must be done on the fly.